# MySQL query value Math.random gives the same number every time

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to make a random tracking number and INSERT it into my database like this:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO orders SET ?', {tracking_number: Math.round(Math.random()* 100000000000 * Math.random()), order_date: date, ship_method: defaultShippingMethod, number_of_products: numberOfProducts}, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return next();
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

but if I were to try to use a variable like this:

```
let trackingNum = Math.round(Math.random()* 100000000000 * Math.random())

db.query('INSERT INTO orders SET ?', {tracking_number: trackingNum, order_date: date, ship_method: defaultShippingMethod, number_of_products: numberOfProducts}, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return next();
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    });
```

the number inserted into my database is 2147483647 every time.

I have no idea what is going on

EDIT: The number was too big. It seems like 2147483647 is the max range for an INT in mysql or something along those lines. Either decrease the number the random val is multiplied by or store the value in a VARCHAR.

Comment: it's because that `let trackingNum = ...` is only ever executed once. After that, every time `db.query(...)` runs, `trackingNum` has the same value.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I was thinking that but all of my code is inside a function. I printed out trackingNum and it is a sufficiently random number every time, but for whatever reason, when I use the variable in my query it inserts 2147483647. This means that my variable is actually being reset and is a value I want, but the query itself is reading it as 2147483647

Comment: you'll need to show us more code then, that allows us to see under what conditions this code executes.(PS there's no need to multiply by the result of `Math.random()` twice, once is perfectly good enough!)

Comment: your random number is to big. shrink the number to be lower then 2147483647 or change the field format on mysql to bigint

Comment: using math.random twice is going to produce an uneven distribution; for an equal chance of each number just call it once.  except even then your round() is making the results vary between 0 and 100000000000 with a lower chance of the two extremes; use .trunc() instead to get an even chance of each of the numbers 0 to 99999999999 or .trunc and multiply by 100000000001 for 0 to 100000000000

Comment: @YairI Thanks so much, you are exactly right, decreasing the number I multiplied by fixed the issue.